# How to manage Handlers in an add-on?

Tags: python, add-on

What is the best way to manage handlers in an add-on?

I am making an add-on that uses the `scene_update_pre` handler. In the `register()` function, I have added this line:

```
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(my_handler)
```

The issue is how do I setup the `unregister()` function to remove the handler if the add-on is disabled? I can't use `pop` because it might mess up another add-on, correct?

Whats the best practice when making an Add-on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is simple:

```
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(my_handler)
```

Blender will call `unregister()` in the moment you untick the addon in the *User Preferences*.

`my_handler` is a function in the global scope of your script, and you append it to the scene update handlers. You can remove it in the same way, by giving a function reference to `remove()`. It doesn't work if you try to remove a handler callback from outside, because another script hasn't the same function.

Comment: With a draw_handler, you pass the "handle" to be removed.  For app handlers, you remove the function, no handle is returned with bpy.app_handlers.scene_update_pre.append(my_function)