# Internal script modification

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to modify an internal file but I don't know how to replace it. 
Indeed, I want to modify a script in `Templates>Python>Operator File Import` but I don't find a way to do it in the text editor. Maybe it's obvious, in fact I also don't find my answer in the existing questions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that template files cant be modified, what you may do instead is to copy the content of the template file in a new text block and tweak it there

Comment: You think I can keep the main part of the template in a new text block (or in an extern script I guess ?) and make them both run will not be a problem ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: It appears this is in relation to  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146160/15543 which is a case of, quoting @Sambler, using it as a "_starting point_"  when creating another script. The template isn't modified, the script is a modified version of it.  Save the modified script, with .py extension and install as addon, or simply save in blend file and  run the script from the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates files are only meant to be used as starting points, you don't need to replace any of them.

In blenders text editor choose the *Templates->Python->Operator File Import*, modify the contents in the text editor and save it to a file using *Text->Save As*. The best place to save the file would be in your [config folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html). You could save it to your desktop and use the *Install Addon From File* button.

Once you have saved it into your configs addon folder, you can enable the addon in your preferences and use your import addon.